# Flex/C++: 'yypanic' was not declared in scope, error: redefinition of 'class yFlexLexer', 'yyFlexLexer' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, cmake, flex-lexer

Hello I am trying to use Flex with C++. After reading the Flex Manual I started working on a small example to build my project off.

I came up with this small example initially.

```cpp
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>  
#include <sstream>  
#include <string>    
#include <streambuf>
#include <fstream> 

int main() {
    std::string stringvalues = "TOKEN TEST 123";
    std::istringstream inputStringStream(stringvalues);

    std::istream& inputStream = inputStringStream;
    std::ofstream outputStream("test.txt");

    yyFlexLexer myTest(inputStream, outputStream);
}
```

Inside a build folder when I do `cmake ..` then hit `make` I get the following error:

```
alfredo@alfredo-ThinkPad-T440p:~/repos/FlexCpp/build$ make
[ 20%] Linking CXX static library libkeywords.a
[ 20%] Built target keywords
[ 40%] Building CXX object src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/main.cpp.o
/home/alfredo/repos/FlexCpp/src/back-end/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/alfredo/repos/FlexCpp/src/back-end/main.cpp:17:5: error: ‘yyFlexLexer’ was not declared in this scope
   17 |     yyFlexLexer myTest(inputStream, outputStream);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/build.make:80: src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

What is strange is that if I comment out the last line in main.cpp

```cpp
    //yyFlexLexer myTest(inputStream, outputStream);
```

I get the following error:

```
lexer.l: In member function ‘virtual int yyFlexLexer::yylex()’:
lexer.l:172:1: error: ‘yypanic’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/flex/include/FlexLexer.h: At global scope:
/home/alfredo/repos/FlexCpp/src/back-end/lexer.yy.cc:49:25: error: redefinition of ‘class yyFlexLexer’
   49 |     #define yyFlexLexer yyFlexLexer
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/alfredo/repos/FlexCpp/src/back-end/lexer.yy.cc:49:25: note: previous definition of ‘class yyFlexLexer’
   49 |     #define yyFlexLexer yyFlexLexer
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/build.make:94: src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/lexer.yy.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: src/back-end/CMakeFiles/Foo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

My project directory looks like the following.

```
backend/
  |- main.cpp (what you saw ealier)
  |- CMakeLists.txt
  |- keywords.hxx (contains enum tokens and struct)
  |- lexer.l 
  |- lexer.yy.cc (this will be generated by lexer.l when we compile with c++
                  we set %option c++ in our lexer.l file )
```

Here is what my lexer.l looks like

```
    /* we dont have an interactive session. */ 
%option never-interactive


    /* we will handle the nodefault rule. */
%option nodefault

    /* we dont want yyinput() and yyunput(). */
%option noinput nounput


    /* don't include <unistd.h> we dont need it. */
%option nounistd


    /* 
        not needed for now, in the future when users can work 
        with multiple files we can start using it.
    */
%option noyywrap


    /* 
        these two options are doubled to get more detailed reports.
        write performance report to stderr.
    */
%option perf-report perf-report

    /* write statistics summary to stderr. */
%option verbose verbose

    /* generate warning messages for mistakes. */
%option warn

    /* maintain current line number in yylineno. */
%option yylineno

%option c++



    /* c items that can be used in the rules section */
%{
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <keywords.hxx>



int iskeyword(char * keyword);



%}

digit      [0-9]
exponent   [ee][-+]?{digit}+


id_start   [_a-za-z]
id_after   {id_start}|{digit}



    /*===================rules===================*/
%% 

    /* a bunch of rules */

%% 
    /*=================user-code=================*/
#include <keywords.hxx>

    /*As mentioned by Flex manual we include this if our main() is not in this file */
#include <FlexLexer.h>

int iskeyword(char * keyword){
    for(int index = 0; index < NUM_KEYWORDS; index++){
        if(strcmp(keywords[index].keyWord, keyword)){
            return keywords[index].token;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(
    TestingProj
)


set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -isystem /usr/local/flex/include")

find_package(FLEX REQUIRED)


add_library(keywords keywords.hxx)
set_target_properties(keywords PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(keywords PUBLIC ./)


FLEX_TARGET(
    gen_lexer
    lexer.l
    lexer.yy.cc
)

add_executable(
    Foo
    main.cpp
    ${FLEX_gen_lexer_OUTPUTS}
)

target_link_libraries(Foo PUBLIC keywords)
target_link_libraries(Foo PUBLIC ${FLEX_LIBRARIES})
```

If I log the following

```
message("FLEX_FOUND ${FLEX_FOUND}")
message("FLEX_EXECUTABLE ${FLEX_EXECUTABLE}")
message("FLEX_VERSION ${FLEX_VERSION}")
message("FLEX_LIBRARIES ${FLEX_LIBRARIES}")
message("FLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS ${FLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

I get

```
FLEX_FOUND TRUE
FLEX_EXECUTABLE /usr/local/flex/bin/flex
FLEX_VERSION 2.6.4
FLEX_LIBRARIES /usr/local/flex/lib/libfl.so
FLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/flex/include
```

I also tired to following from the Flex Manual. Did not help.

> If you want to create multiple (different) lexer classes, you use the ‘-P’ flag (or the
> prefix= option) to rename each yyFlexLexer to some other ‘xxFlexLexer’. You then
> can include <FlexLexer.h> in your other sources once per lexer class, first renaming
> yyFlexLexer as follows:
> #undef yyFlexLexer
> #define yyFlexLexer xxFlexLexer
> #include <FlexLexer.h>
> #undef yyFlexLexer
> #define yyFlexLexer zzFlexLexer
> #include <FlexLexer.h>

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have spent a lot of hours trying to get Flex and C++ to work. I was able to get Flex and plain C to work it is just c++ I am having trouble. My best guess as of right as of posting is that there is an issue with the `FlexLexer.h` file. Some reason other projects that ive built from source bulid a `FlexLexer.h` file in their `/include` folder. As far as im aware right now it points to the correct location of `FlexLexer.h` which is my case is at `/usr/local/flex/include/FlexLexer.h:` Or it could be something wrong with my `.cmake` file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "As mentioned by Flex manual we include this if our main() is not in this file" - As far as I understand [that documentation](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_node/flex_19.html), with `%option c++` the generated file will **automatically** include `FlexLexer.h`. No needs to explicitly include that file from `lexer.l`. But in you `main.cpp` you need to include `FlexLexer.h`, otherwise a compiler has no information about `yyFlexLexer` class.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for the reply. In the link you provided that quote is not mentioned but here is the manual that I read [doc](https://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/flex.pdf) which does include that quote. Maybe the manual I read is old ?
Here is my output with your feedback applied. For now ill keep look into why this is happening. 
`lexer.l: In member function ‘virtual int yyFlexLexer::yylex()’:
lexer.l:85:1: error: ‘yypanic’ was not declared in this scope`
Any further suggestions are appreciated :3

Edit: format fix

Comment: @Tsyvarev I got it to work! kinda... If I get rid of the line `%option nodefault` in my lexer.l file I can compile c++ and run a sample lexer ! I am not sure why getting rid of this works. Im not getting any warnings from `Flex` that would indicate this. In my `lexer.yy.cc` if I include the `nodefault` option it does generate `#line 101 "lexer.l" yypanic("flex scanner jammed" );` but when I get rid of it it does not generate that line and my program works ! I will post another update if I can make the program work with the `%option nodefault`  in my `lexer.l` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

I was able to solve it by first following the comment left by Tysvarev I am quoting them.

"No needs to explicitly include that file from lexer.l. But in you main.cpp you need to include FlexLexer.h, otherwise a compiler has no information about yyFlexLexer class"

Then inside a `%{ ... %}` block, I defined yypanic like this

```
void yypanic( char* errorMessage);
```

finally in the user code I wrote

```cpp
void yypanic(char * errorMessage) {
    std::cout << errorMessage << std::endl;
}
```